# How do you fix an abnormal message_id return from Firebase Cloud Messaging or what does it mean?

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm getting a return like below with notifications not being received:

```
{
    "multicast_id": 339554596924119421,
    "success": 1,
    "failure": 0,
    "canonical_ids": 0,
    "results": [{
        "message_id": "0:1593443824341654%c4860296c4860296"
    }]
}
```

When I expect a return like this one below, and a delivered notification:

```
{
    "multicast_id": 1714438464855660605,
    "success": 1,
    "failure": 0,
    "canonical_ids": 0,
    "results": [{
        "message_id": "1593203838780899"
    }]
}
```

This issue is arising after deleting the firebase instance in app and getting a new token. What does the difference between message_id's mean or how does someone fix it?

Comment: From Firebase Support: 

Both of those values are just different message_ids. Both are fine and should mean that the request was successful.

Comment: However I still don't get the notification at all on an initial install with react native. I checked on the native iOS side and the notification is never received. This makes me wonder if the token registration only gets partially completed.